# MVC - how can I universally specify what should happen OnBegin and OnComplete of Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

there are some actions I would like to globally specify on Ajax.BeginForm. (For example, user clicking any button should be disabled till we hear back from the Ajax request - OnComplete event).  How should I efficiently accomplish this in one single place instead of hijacking OnBegin and OnComplete of every single instance of Ajax.BeginForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible with MSAjax. On the other hand if you use jQuery there's the [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) which allows you to achieve exactly this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#spinner').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#spinner').hide();
    }
});
```